# Unix:merge multiple CSV files with same header by keeping the header of the first file

Tags: unix, csv

I have to merge multiple CSV files with same headers.
I have to keep the header of the first file and remove headers of all the other files and merge them and create one master file.

file 1:

```
Id,city,name ,location
1,NA,JACK,CA
```

file 2:

```
ID,city,name,location
2,NY,JERRY,NY
```

output:

```
Id,city,name,location
1,NA,JACK,CA
2,NY,JERRY,NY
```

Currently I am using this code:

```
ls *.csv | xargs -n 1 tail -n+2 > master.csv
```

This code will merge the files perfectly , but as I need the header of the first file, this will not give me the header.

What should I do?

Comment: This is an append operation, not merge. Perhaps someone can edit the question title to better represent the content.

Answer (score 88, accepted):

```
awk 'FNR==1 && NR!=1{next;}{print}' *.csv
```

tested on solaris unix:

```
> cat file1.csv
Id,city,name ,location
1,NA,JACK,CA
>
> cat file2.csv
ID,city,name,location
2,NY,JERRY,NY
>
> nawk 'FNR==1 && NR!=1{next;}{print}' *.csv
Id,city,name ,location
1,NA,JACK,CA
2,NY,JERRY,NY
>
```

Explanation given by [kevin-d](https://stackoverflow.com/users/353308):

> FNR is the number of lines (records) read so far in the current file.
>   NR is the number of lines read overall. So the condition 'FNR==1 &&
>   NR!=1{next;}' says, "Skip this line if it's the first line of the
>   current file, and at least 1 line has been read overall." This has the
>   effect of printing the CSV header of the first file while skipping it
>   in the rest.

[Link](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/06/awk-nawk-gawk/) for the difference between [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) and [nawk](/questions/tagged/nawk)

Comment: Explanation:
FNR is the number of lines (records) read so far in the current file.
NR is the number of lines read overall.
So the condition 'FNR==1 && NR!=1{next;}' says, "Skip this line if it's the first line of the current file, and at least 1 line has been read overall." This has the effect of printing the CSV header of the first file while skipping it in the rest.

Comment: For the noobs like me... I added the `> master.csv` to the end to create the new file with all the data instead of it running the the CLI

Answer (score 2):

If Perl is an option:

`perl -ne 'print if $. > 1 or ! $h; $h=1; close ARGV if eof' *.csv > master.csv`

`$.` is the line number.
It is NOT reset automatically between files, so `close ARGV if eof` is needed.
`$h` records if the header has already been printed.

Answer (score 0):

Just as a side note for everyone who uses the accepted solution of this thread (like me as well :)) - be careful that this code will fail if the header contains new lines, i.e., something like

```
column1,"column\nwith\new line",column2
value1,value2,value3
...
```

In this case, only the part `column1,"column` will be considered as the header and the rest of the header will be considered a normal row (which will completely break your final CSV). If you have a header with a new line inside, the only solution I can think about is to use a "full-fledged" csv reader library which will be able to correctly read the header.

But despite of this minor issue, the line above saved me from a lot of head ache. :D

Answer (score 0):

Another convenient way to accomplish this is using the `csvkit` package.
First, install the package
`sudo apt install csvkit`
Next, run the `csvstack` command:
`csvstack myFile1.csv myFile2.csv > myCombinedOutputFile.csv`
You could also combine more than 2 files. Each file could contain a header. Only the header from the first file is used and included in the output file.

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
ini_set('auto_detect_line_endings', true);
$dir = "include/*.csv";
$returnVal = array();
foreach (glob($dir) as $file) {
    $header = null;
    $file = fopen($file, 'r') or die('Unable to open file!');
    while(($row = fgetcsv($file)) !== false){
        if($header === null){
            $header = $row;
            continue;
        }
        $newRow = array();
        for($i = 0; $i<count($row); $i++){

            $newRow[] = $row[$i];   
        }
        if($newRow[0] == null)
        break;
        else
        $returnVal[] = $newRow;
    }
    fclose($file);
}
//var_dump($returnVal);
$output = fopen("file.csv",'w') or die("Can't open output");
fputcsv($output, array('Date','close','open'));
foreach($returnVal as $product) {
    fputcsv($output, $product);
}
```

fclose($output) or die("Can't close php://output"); 
?>

Comment: Pasting code is not enough. Tell us something about it.