# Read all the csv file in a folder and only showed a single header in the output file

Tags: csv, batch-file

I would like to read all the csv file in the folder and compile it using an awk file. Below is the code that i had wrote:

```
@echo off

del c_1.csv

setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

set file2=*.csv
set outputfile=c_1.csv

REM get header:
set /p header=<%outputfile%

for %%i in (*.csv) do (
if not exist %header% (
nawk -f "c_1.awk" *.csv >> c_1.csv
)
if exist %header% (
nawk -f more +1 "c_1.awk" *.csv >> c_1.csv
)
)

echo done!

setlocal

pause
goto:eof
```

But the header still printed in my output file and it had also printed extra data that is incorrect also. Ur help will be appreciated.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Will this not do what you want?

```dos
nawk "FNR==1 && NR!=1{next;}{print}" *.csv>c_1.csv
```

*Idea taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16890582/unixmerge-multiple-csv-files-with-same-header-by-keeping-the-header-of-the-firs).*

**Edit**
As it seems I understood your request wrongly, *(I didn't properly read the question and assumed you were concatenating files, but only retaining the header on the first)*. You appear to be running an awk script, `c_1.awk` on all csv's in the current directory, if the header of any csv doesn't match the input from `outputfile` then you're intending to 'compile' the entire file, if it does then you're wanting to bypass that header.

The main problem with your batch-file lies with the fact that `if exist` doesn't tell you if the content of `%header%` is empty, for that you'll need `If Defined header`. That said, as you have already deleted the input file, your `set /p` command would output an error `The system cannot find the file specified.` and header will still not be defined.

I think that what you should really do is adjust your awk script such that it takes the header to match as an input parameter. That would be much better than trying to check the content in a different language then run one of two awk commands depending upon that content.

Comment: Not, because i having another code in the c_1.awk to analysis the data.

Comment: Apologies for misunderstanding your intent. I have added an addition to the above post as an edit.