# How do i read multiple CSV files with bash and append them to another one correctly?

Tags: linux, bash, exec

So i've been trying to make a program that reads the content of 5 CSV files, named export**n**.csv. The content of these files needs to be put in an output file named *merged.csv*. I became confused about `exec`, because i don't know where to put it. Here's the code:

```
#!/bin/bash

tc=1
for file_index in `ls export*.csv`                    
do
    if [ $tc -eq 1 ]; then
        fline=`head -1 export1.csv`           
        echo $fline > merged.csv
        let "tc++"
    else
        sed 1d | while read riga; do          
            echo "$riga,$file_index" >> merged.csv
        done < $file_index
    fi
done
```

The problem is that i don't know where to put `exec` correctly. The first line has to be skipped (except first time), because *merged.csv* should have the first line as field description. The CSV files are structured this way: name,surname,product_code in the first line, and the data next. But how can i correctly cycle through them?

Comment: Your header is going to have one less column than the rest. Also, don't use `ls` as input to `for`, you're creating a whole new process to do what the shell can do already: `for file_index in export*.csv`.

Comment: Please add sample input and your desired output for that sample input to your question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unix:merge multiple CSV files with same header by keeping the header of the first file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16890582/unixmerge-multiple-csv-files-with-same-header-by-keeping-the-header-of-the-firs). You don't need `exec` in your script.

Comment: Your solution is overly complex by at least one order of magnitude (unless you're doing this as an advanced shell script learning exercise ) ;-) .. Assuming you mean your files are numbered in the correct sequence already, i.e. `f01.txt, f02.txt, f03.txt,...` then `cat f01.txt  > merged.txt; mv f01.txt f01.HID ; sed '1d' f*.txt >> merged.txt; mv f01.HID f01.txt` will solve the stated problem. Learn you use the commands available first ;-)  Good luck. And ++ for using code formatting in your first Q!

Comment: Extra : . Note that if you have saved files as `f1.txt, f2.txt....` then `f11.txt` will mess this solution up. So name your files defensively (with leading zeros to keep the default file name sorting correct) ;-)

Comment: i will improve, especially because i need to learn `awk`. Thanks to all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
#!/bin/bash

HEADER="name,surname,product_code"      # define header
MERGED="merged.csv"                     # define output file

echo $HEADER > $MERGED                  # write header in output file
for csv in export*.csv; do              # run over all csv's
    sed "/$HEADER/d" $csv >> $MERGED    # remove first line, append to output file
done
```

Comment: It's working! And in very few lines too! Thanks a lot. I also appreciate the `AWK` solution, though a script is more adaptable so i like this solution more.