# How to append more than 33 files in a gcloud bucket?

Tags: gcloud, gsutil

I use to append datasets in a bucket in gcloud using:

```sh
gsutil compose gs://bucket/obj1 [gs://bucket/obj2 ...] gs://bucket/composite
```

However, today when I tried to append some data the terminal prints the error `CommandException: The compose command accepts at most 33 arguments.`

I didn't know about this restriction. How can I append more than 33 files in my bucket? Is there another command line tool? I would like to avoid to create a virtual machine for what looks like a rather simple task.

I checked the help using `gsutil help compose`. But it didn't help much. There is only a warning saying "Note that there is a limit (currently 32) to the number of components that can
be composed in a single operation." but no hint on a workaround.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you not do it recursively|batch?

**I've not tried this.**

Given an arbitrary list of files (`FILES`)

While there is more than 1 file in `FILES`:

1. Take the first n where n<=33 from `FILES` and `gsutil compose` into temp file
2. If that succeeds, replace the n names in `FILES` with the 1 temp file.
3. Repeat

The file that remains is everything composed.

#### Update

The question piqued my curiosity and gave me an opportunity to improve my bash ;-)

A rough-and-ready proof-of-concept bash script that generates batches of `gsutil compose` commands for arbitrary (limited by the string formatting `%04`) numbers of files.

```sh
GSUTIL="gsutil compose"
BATCH_SIZE="32"

# These may be the same (or no) bucket
SRC="gs://bucket01/"
DST="gs://bucket02/"

# Generate test LST
FILES=()
for N in $(seq -f "%04g" 1 100); do
    FILES+=("${SRC}/file-${N}")
done

function squish() {
  LST=("$@")
  LEN=${#LST[@]}

  if [ "${LEN}" -le "1" ]; then
    # Empty array; nothing to do
    return 1
  fi

  # Only unique for this configuration; be careful
  COMPOSITE=$(printf "${DST}/composite-%04d" ${LEN})

  if [ "${LEN}" -le "${BATCH_SIZE}" ]; then
    # Batch can be composed with one command
    echo "${GSUTIL} ${LST[@]} ${COMPOSITE}"
    return 1
  fi

  # Compose 1st batch of files
  # NB Provide start:size
  echo "${GSUTIL} ${LST[@]:0:${BATCH_SIZE}} ${COMPOSITE}"

  # Remove batch from LST
  # NB Provide start (to end is implied)
  REM=${LST[@]:${BATCH_SIZE}}

  # Prepend composite from above batch to the next run
  NXT=(${COMPOSITE} ${REM[@]})

  squish "${NXT[@]}"
}

squish "${FILES[@]}"
```

Running with `BATCH_SIZE=3`, no buckets and 12 files yields:

```sh
gsutil compose file-0001 file-0002 file-0003 composite-0012
gsutil compose composite-0012 file-0004 file-0005 composite-0010
gsutil compose composite-0010 file-0006 file-0007 composite-0008
gsutil compose composite-0008 file-0008 file-0009 composite-0006
gsutil compose composite-0006 file-0010 file-0011 composite-0004
gsutil compose composite-0004 file-0012 composite-0002
```

> **NOTE** How `composite-0012` is created by the first command but then knitted into the subsequent command.

I'll leave it to you to improve throughput by not threading the output from each step into the next, parallelizing the `gsutil compose` commands across the list chopped into batches and then compose the batches.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I use the code provide in a question (linked below) to append the files locally using Linux shell. However, your answer might be useful for Windows users. Link to the question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16890582/unixmerge-multiple-csv-files-with-same-header-by-keeping-the-header-of-the-firs

Comment: You described the files as being on GCS already and, in that case, it is more efficient to compose the files (service-side) on GCS.

Comment: Nice, @DazWilkin. I've adapted the function [here](https://gist.github.com/marpontes/c58ccbd0b542ab874e55891085c42f90). What mine does different: 1) Uses the last original argument to to be the final composite file; 2) Returns the exit code 0. I'm using as part of a script that exports arbitrary BigQuery tables to single CSVs for migration purposes.

Answer (score 1):

The docs say that you may only combine 32 components [in a single operation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/objects/compose), but there is [no limit to the number of components that can make up a composite object](https://cloud.google.com/storage/quotas#objects).

So, if you have more than 32 objects to concatenate, you may perform multiple compose operations, composing 32 objects at a time until you eventually get all of them composed together.